# How correctly to access own Logger class

Tags: vb.net

I got my own simple logger class in class library project which is used in many other projects belongs to my solution. Right now i am using it in this way in every class that consume it in top:

```
Private Logger As New Logger("C:\someLogFile.log")
```

then later in code i am using it:

```
Logger.LogIt("Start part extracting files...")
```

I always need in every class create instance of it and its boring sometimes... I know i could create static Logger class and overcome the issue but would it be correct way or the way i am doing is ok according to OOP? What do you think?

***EDIT: What do you think about this solution which is using Interface i've just implemented it what do you think?:***

**First project (Logger project) which is used in many other projects around one solution:**

```
Imports System.IO

    Public NotInheritable Class Logger
#Region "Fields"
        Private Shared ReadOnly _locker As New Object()
#End Region
#Region "Constructors"
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Log function"
    Public Sub LogIt(ByVal msg As String, ByVal logMessage As String, Optional Path As String = "", Optional ByVal IsDebug As Boolean = False)
        If File.Exists(Path) Then
            If IsDebug Then
                Debug.Print(DateTime.Now & "> | " & msg & " | " & logMessage)
            Else
                Using w As TextWriter = File.AppendText(Path)
                    w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now & "> | " & msg & " | " & logMessage)
                    w.Flush()
                End Using
            End If
        Else
            If IsDebug Then
                Debug.Print(DateTime.Now & "> | " & msg & " | " & logMessage)
            Else
                SyncLock _locker
                    Using w As TextWriter = File.CreateText(Path)
                        w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now & "> | " & msg & " | " & logMessage)
                        w.Flush()
                    End Using
                End SyncLock
            End If
        End If
    End Sub



#End Region
```

**i added additionaly ILog.vb interface to this project:**

```
Public Interface ILog

    Property LoggerPath As String
    Sub LogIt(ByVal msg As String, ByVal logMessage As String, ByVal Path As String, Optional ByVal IsDebug As Boolean = False)

End Interface
```

**Now one of class which would use Logger for instance this below. (LoggerPath will come to constructor of MainProcessRunner from xml serialization on the beggining) e.g C:/file.txt:**

```
Public Class MainProcessRunner
    Implements ILog

    Private Property LoggerPath As String Implements ILog.LoggerPath
    Private CollectionList As New List(Of ImportRunner)

    Public Sub New(ByVal LoggerPath As String)

        Me.LoggerPath = LoggerPath
CollectionList.Add(New ImportRunner(GPCollectTimePeriod.EveryMidnight, KpiName.Availability, MobileGenerationName.GSM, Me))

 For Each item In CollectionList
            If TypeOf item Is ICollectPeriod Then
                Dim runDaily As ICollectPeriod = TryCast(item, ICollectPeriod)
                runDaily.RunDaily()
            End If
        Next

...

   Public Sub LogIt(msg As String, logMessage As String, Path As String, Optional IsDebug As Boolean = False) Implements ILog.LogIt
        Dim Logger As New Logger
        Logger.LogIt(Alert.Write(MsgType.INFO), logMessage, Me.LoggerPath, True)
    End Sub

End class
```

**As you can see inside constructor i am calling other class by:**

```
 runDaily.RunDaily()
```

**then inside below class ILog interface is passed by so therefore i will have log path  already from MainProcessRunner and then i need to only fill msgtype and message string:**

```
Imports ImportJob

Public Class ImportRunner
    Implements ICollectPeriod

    Private Log As ILog
        Private BeginImport As New ImportStart
        Private GPCollectTimePeriodInMinutes As GPCollectTimePeriod
        Private KpiName As KpiName
        Private MobileGeneration As MobileGenerationName

        Public Sub New(ByVal GPCollectTimePeriodInMinutes As GPCollectTimePeriod, ByVal KpiName As KpiName, ByVal MobileGenerationName As MobileGenerationName, ByVal log As ILog)
            Me.GPCollectTimePeriodInMinutes = GPCollectTimePeriodInMinutes
            Me.KpiName = KpiName
            Me.MobileGeneration = MobileGenerationName
            Me.Log = log
        End Sub

        Public Sub RunDaily() Implements ICollectPeriod.RunDaily

            Log.LogIt(Alert.Write(MsgType.INFO), "sdsd", Log.LoggerPath, True)

    ....

        End Class
```

**In this line Log.LoggerPath is known as (C:/file.txt:)**

```
 Log.LogIt(Alert.Write(MsgType.INFO), "sdsd", Log.LoggerPath, True)
```

**From class ImpotStart i can pass through Log as ILog further to the next class constructor if needed if that class would implement ILog interface. and so on..
What do you think about that solution?**

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a design pattern ["Singleton"](http://www.dofactory.com/net/singleton-design-pattern) which assures only a single instance (the singleton) of the class can be created:

```
using System;

namespace Singleton.Structural
{

  class Singleton
  {
    private static Singleton _instance;


    // Constructor is 'protected'
    protected Singleton()
    {

    }


    public static Singleton Instance()
    {

      // Uses lazy initialization.
      // Note: this is not thread safe.

      if (_instance == null)
      {
        _instance = new Singleton();
      }


      return _instance;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i edited my oryginal post can you please take a look and tell me what do you think about this interface solution i've implemented

Comment: I think that you don't need to derive from any interface but simple have to use the well-known pattern "Singleton"

Comment: i am intrested whether this interface solution is correctly implemented? This is how this could be resolved using interface i mean is this one of correct way of using interfaces itself?

Comment: This your question is different from the first/initial "How correctly to access own Logger class" that I have answered.

Comment: ok then using singletong could be not so good because then i would need to keep reference to every construcotr i am using as this will ne instance and not shared.

Answer (score 1):

The OOP way would be to perform dependency injection to send the same instance of the Logger class into each class that requires it.

However, there is absolutely nothing wrong with just making your class static.

Comment: i edited my oryginal post can you please take a look and tell me what do you think about this interface solution i've implemented.

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't really what I was talking about. You'd have your main process runner take an `ILog` as a constructor parameter, then whatever constructs main process runner would pass an instance of `Logger` to it. Anything else requiring access to the Log would be passed the same instance of `Logger`. An IoC container such as `Ninject` could be utilized to maintain the life cycle of the `Logger` instance if there is no composition root in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the right thing only. If you tired of calling object.Method name.

Put this (i.e object method ) in base class of you project with a Common Method and call that method in everypage.

```html
Public void LogError(string error)
{
Logger.LogIt(error);
}
```

You can call the same by LogError in catch statement.

Better you read below link for better Logging method for you project

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling

Comment: i edited my oryginal post can you please take a look and tell me what do you think about this interface solution i've implemented

Answer (score 0):

i read that static/share can be used if some object is used in almost every area in solution so logger is good enough to use it as static/shared and make change only to message text and path pass by its constructor.

I dont think that singleton could be good in this case because then he would need to track his reference to every class, and it would be really complicated if he would have 20 projects with multiple classes over one solution so i think its better to make Logger static.

or just stay what you doing right now that every class has their own Logger instance. The problem could be with file path only if you got big flow of a data.